# Django 1.9 FormView never reach get_context_data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a FormView called LeagueTransferView based on a form LeagueTransferForm.

I'm trying to override get_context_data to add extra players to render in the template.

But get_context_data is never reached. It's working fine on other views like, DetailView, ListView,...

I'm missing something?

Below my configuration

**View**

```
class LeagueTransferView(FormView):
    template_name = 'hockey/league/transfer_market.html'
    form_class = LeagueTransferForm
    success_url = ''

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('----NEVER REACHED----')
        context = super(LeagueTransferView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        petitioner = get_object_or_404(Team, user=self.request.user.profile, league=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['players'] = Player.objects.filter(leagues=self.kwargs['pk']).exclude(teams=petitioner)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        petitioner = get_object_or_404(Team, user=self.request.user.profile, league=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form = self.form_class(initial={'league': self.kwargs['pk'], 'petitioner': petitioner})
        form.fields['offered_player'].queryset = petitioner.players
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            transfer = form.save(commit=False)
            team = Team.objects.filter(league=transfer.league, players__in=[transfer.requested_player])
            if not team:  # free agent
                transfer.status = 1
                messages.success(request, _('transfer succeeded'))
            else:
                print(team)
                transfer.player_owner = team[0]
                if transfer.petitioner.user is None:  # bot team
                    transfer.status = 1
                    messages.success(request, _('transfer succeeded'))
                else:
                    messages.success(request, _('transfer waiting for confirmation by player owner'))
            transfer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('hockey_dashboard'))

        petitioner = get_object_or_404(Team, user=self.request.user.profile, league=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.fields['offered_player'].queryset = petitioner.players
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**FORM**

```
class LeagueTransferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transfer
        fields = ['league', 'requested_player', 'offered_player', 'player_owner', 'petitioner']
        labels = {
            'requested_player': _('Requested player'),
            'offered_player': _('Offered player'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'requested_player': forms.HiddenInput,
            'league': forms.HiddenInput,
            'player_owner': forms.HiddenInput,
            'petitioner': forms.HiddenInput
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is never reaching `get_context_data()` because you have overridden the `get()` method and not calling the `get_context_data()` function there. You need to manually call the `get_context_data()` function at the time of passing `context` to `render()` in your code.

Instead of doing that, i would suggest you to try the below approach where instead of overrriding `get()` and returning your custom response, you only override what is necessary and let Django handle the rest.

```
class LeagueTransferView(FormView):
    template_name = 'hockey/league/transfer_market.html'
    form_class = LeagueTransferForm
    success_url = ''

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeagueTransferView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['players'] = Player.objects.filter(leagues=self.kwargs['pk']).exclude(teams=self.petitioner)
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(LeagueTransferView, self).get_initial()
        initial['league'] = self.kwargs['pk'] # add custom data to initial
        initial['petitioner'] = self.petitioner # add custom data to initial
        return initial

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(LeagueTransferView, self).get_form(form_class)
        # override the queryset
        form.fields['offered_player'].queryset = self.petitioner.players 
        return form

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # only perform 1 query to get 'petitioner'
        self.petitioner = get_object_or_404(Team, user=self.request.user.profile, league=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(LeagueTransferView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You mean like this?
def get(): ....
context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
context['form'] = form
return render(request, self.template_name, context)

Comment: Instead of doing that, override only what is necessary using different methods provided by Django and rest Django will handle for you. Checkout the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py)  for `FormView` for a better understanding of the flow.

Comment: Now I really understood how Django Views works :D. It wasn't clear to me the actual flow. Thank you again